# xCode UIImage EPS format

Tags: image

I am trying to load an EPS format image into my Image View with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appbg-vector-temp.eps"];
    [imageView setImage:img];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

No errors, but i do not see my eps in my ui view.

I got this in my .h file: IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
And i linked the imageView variable to my Image View.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` can't load EPS images. If you stop at that line after you call `imageNamed:` in the debugger, you'll see that your `img` variable is nil. That's because it was unable to load the EPS.